How to authorize a Ruby REST request to the GA4 API using a service account?
I am trying to get a count of views for a given page path from the GA4 API library. I have been able to do so using the Ruby GA4 API client gem google-analytics-data but I want to compare the results using a basic REST request due to significant variations in results between the GA4 Query Explorer and my Ruby API code. Some of the paths produce identical counts but most don't.
I keep getting an error
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/googleauth-1.11.0/lib/googleauth/service_account.rb:87:in `unescape': undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

This error is generated by this line:
credentials = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
     scope: claims[:scope],
     json_key: private_key
  )

The gsub line in my code is not related as the error is generated even when I remove the gsub.
Here is my full code.
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'googleauth'  
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'time'
require './environment' 
error_message = nil

module GoogleAnalytics

    def self.make_ga4_rest_request(body)
      # Define GA4 Reporting API endpoint URL
      
      endpoint = "https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet"

      key_data = JSON.parse(File.read(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE))
      
      private_key = key_data['private_key'].gsub("\n", "")

      puts private_key.inspect
   
      claims = {
         iss: SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
         scope: AUDIENCE,
         aud: AUDIENCE,
         exp: (Time.now + 60 * 60).to_i  # JWT expires in 1 hour
         }
        
      credentials = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
         scope: claims[:scope],
         json_key: private_key
      )
        
      jwt = credentials.authorization.id_token
        
      headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer #{jwt}"
      }
             
      # Prepare the Net::HTTP request object
      uri = URI(endpoint)
      https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
      https.use_ssl = true
      request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)

      # request.set_header!(*headers) newer ruby versions
      headers.each do |key, value|
        request.add_field(key, value)
      end

      request.body = body.to_json

            # Send the request and handle response
      response = https.request(request)
      if response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
        JSON.parse(response.body)
      else
        error_message = "Error making GA4 request: #{response.code} - #{response.message}"  
        puts "Error message: #{error_message}"
        puts "Response object: #{response.body}"  # Print thend
      end  
    end
end

Here is the body for my query included for completeness
 body = {
                      "reportRequests": [
                        {
                        "property": "properties/#{PROPERTY_ID}", 
                        "dateRanges": [{"startDate": report_start_date, "endDate": report_end_date}],
                        "metrics": [{"expression": "ga:screenPageViews"}],
                        "dimensions": [{"name": "ga:pagePath"}],
                        "filters": [{"field": "ga:pagePath", "operator": "REGEXP_CONTAINS", "value": page}], 
                        }
                      ]
                    }


require 'googleauth'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'time'
require './environment'  # Make sure you've defined SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE, SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, AUDIENCE, PROPERTY_ID, etc.

module GoogleAnalytics
  def self.make_ga4_rest_request(body)
    # Define GA4 Reporting API endpoint URL
    endpoint = "https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet"

    key_data = JSON.parse(File.read(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE))
    private_key = key_data['private_key'].gsub("\n", '')

    claims = {
      iss: SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
      scope: AUDIENCE,
      aud: AUDIENCE,
      exp: (Time.now + 60 * 60).to_i  # JWT expires in 1 hour
    }

    credentials = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
      scope: claims[:scope],
      json_key: private_key
    )

    jwt = credentials.authorization.id_token

    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': "Bearer #{jwt}"
    }

    # Prepare the Net::HTTP request object
    uri = URI(endpoint)
    https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    https.use_ssl = true
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)

    headers.each do |key, value|
      request.add_field(key, value)
    end

    request.body = body.to_json

    # Send the request and handle response
    response = https.request(request)
    if response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
      JSON.parse(response.body)
    else
      error_message = "Error making GA4 request: #{response.code} - #{response.message}"
      puts "Error message: #{error_message}"
      puts "Response object: #{response.body}"
    end
  end
end

# Example usage:
body = {
  "reportRequests": [
    {
      "property": "properties/#{PROPERTY_ID}",
      "dateRanges": [{"startDate": report_start_date, "endDate": report_end_date}],
      "metrics": [{"expression": "ga:screenPageViews"}],
      "dimensions": [{"name": "ga:pagePath"}],
      "filters": [{"field": "ga:pagePath", "operator": "REGEXP_CONTAINS", "value": page}]
    }
  ]
}

result = GoogleAnalytics.make_ga4_rest_request(body)
puts result

Make sure to replace the placeholders (SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE, SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, AUDIENCE, PROPERTY_ID, etc.) with your actual values. This modified code should correctly authorize your REST request to the GA4 API using the service account credentials.

Apart from some redundant code setting the auth header I don't see any differences between your code any mine. The error occurs in the gem before the request is made to the API at credentials =.

THe issue was I needed an IO to the service account JSON file instead of the private key string extracted from it.
